# How to convert the string '1.000,0.001' to the complex number (1+0.001j)?

Tags: python, complex-numbers

The best I could come up with is

```
s = '1.000,0.001'
z = [float(w) for w in s.split(',')]
x = complex(z[0],z[1])
```

Is there a shorter, cleaner, nicer way?

Comment: `x=complex(s.split(',')[0],s.split(',')[1])` without using z

Comment: That's parsing for you - what you did seems perfectly fine and safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a more concise way, but it's not really any cleaner and it's certainly not clearer.

```
x = complex(*[float(w) for w in '1.000,.001'.split(',')])
```

Comment: I am not an expert. What is the complex(*z) notation? Where can I read about it and what it does?

Comment: `complex` is a constructor that returns a complex number. Here is an explanation of complex numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: I am being dense. I meant the '\*' in 'complex(\*'. What does the '*' do?

Comment: The `*` expands the iterable inside the function call.  See the documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine.  The only improvement I could suggest is to use

```
complex(*z)
```

If you want to one-liner it:

```
>>> complex(*map(float, s.split(',')))
(1+0.001j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do the slightly shorter

```
real, imag = s.split(',')
x = complex(float(real), float(imag))
```

without involving the list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

If you can trust the data to not be dangerous or want this for code golf:

```
>>> eval('complex(%s)' % s)
(1+0.001j)
```